# How to I make OS X move files between hard drives instead of copying when dragging and dropping?

Tags: macos, finder

I keep my system files on the internal hard drive and often move downloaded files and so on out to the external hard drive.

Is there a way to make Mac OS X move files instead of copying when dragging and dropping between different volumes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Command</kbd> while dragging the file.

This will move it instead of copying—you should see the plus sign disappear.